# Android SQLite old data

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm testing an application using a SQLite database. When I run the project in the emulator (ie reinstall) the old data from the previous install still exists in the database. Is there something like an unInstall method I can call to wipe the old data and start fresh?

Comment: You're probably better off coding an "erase data" option. Users might not like you erasing data when you reinstall the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the DATABASE_VERSION field in your code. In the next run the database will be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the data of your application from DDMS. In File Explorer find the home folder of your application (usually, `/data/data/<package_name>`) and delete there your database file. During the next run of your application a new database will be created.